# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.(informix)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, informix, dbproviderfactories

I have an old application and after a long time when i try to test it  .I get the following exception :

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

My code :

```
 public DBConnection(string ConnectionString)
        {
            this.providerFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("IBM.Data.Informix");//Exception here
            this.connection = new IfxConnection();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConnectionString))
            {
                this.connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["r_informix"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                this.connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["r_informix"].ToString();
            }
            command = this.connection.CreateCommand();
        }
```

---

I try to do the following solution [here](http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.com/2011/11/unable-to-find-requested-net-framework.html)

```
</runtime>
 <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <add name="IBM.Data.Informix"
              invariant="IBM.Data.Informix.Client"
              description="Informix Data Provider for .NET"
              type="IBM.Data.Informix,
                  IBM.Data.Informix,
                  Version=3.0.0.2,
                  Culture=Neutral,
                  PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
but In vain ...
```

Comment: In my case, it was solved by setting "Enable 32-bit applications" as "true" in the IIS Application Pool Advanced Settings.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [MSDN documentation for the GetFactory function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h508h681.aspx) the parameter provided should match with the invariant name of the provider factory, which is set as IBM.Data.Informix.Client in your config file but you are passing IBM.Data.Informix (without .Client).

Comment: I did that first but the same problem

Comment: You mention that this is an old application.  Has it ever worked on this machine you are using?  I'm just wondering how sure you are that the provider really is installed.

Comment: no this 's a new machine with a new `informix` version so i change the reference with the new one and build the solution .but i face this error when running the application .

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Informix provider, but according to http://www.cursor-distribution.de/aktuell/documentation/ids_net_bookmap.pdf, if you are running 64 bits Windows you need to set the PATH environment variable to include the path to IfxDotNetIntrinsicModule.dll.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this: [How to register .NET provider](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21429586).
I hope it helps.

Also you could try to install manually IBM.Data.Informix and IBM.Data.DB2 in GAC.